# How to cut pattern on overlapping A4 for print on 100% scale?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, patterns

I am a beginner to Adobe Illustrator, and I am trying to make a pattern for my leather making.

I have made the pattern on a big artboard and then created multiple A4 artboards and I am trying to fit the pattern by overlapping them on different artboards.

[image: Pattern overlapping in A4 Artboard]

This is all fine when I export the Artboards to PDF all the patters are neatly cut exactly how I want it, however, if I try to print it in my printer, and select the scale to 100% so that I want the values of my dimension exactly as I wanted it, it is expanding my pattern and in this process, the edges are getting cut and I can't paste it exactly side by side.

[image: PDF pattern leading to edges being trimmed if I scale to 100%]

What is the method of fixing this? I was thinking of maybe somehow cutting the pattern on exactly half and then putting 1 side in 1 artboard and the other one in another artboard, but I am not sure how to do that.

Can anyone suggest me the most optimal way of doing it?

Comment: See the [TS300 user manua](https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Manual/All/TS300%20series/EN/UG/ug_i_05_01.html)l :  "By selecting Borderless Printing option, you can make prints with no margins." - and note that it doesn't work with A4 or Letter sizes.

Comment: Did you happen to figure out how to do this? I am trying to figure out how to do the same thing. Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Borderless printing is a function of the **printer**. It has nothing to do with any software setting. **Most** end use printers will require a small margin around the entire page, and slightly larger margins for the gripper edge.

I would merely print **three** pages.. adding a center artboard to cover the overlap area. With 3 pieces you can easily stitch them together.

Comment: Is there a way in which I can cut the pattern in half on one artboard and then I can basically shift the entire pattern to a little left and the other one to right?

Comment: Just duplicate things. You don't need to really "cut" anything.